# Pip install is ridiculously slow when install library

Tags: python, pip

I am using pop os 20.04 lts and python v3.8.10.
When i tried to install some library using pip, the speed is very slow, it happens to all library. I can guarantee that my internet connection is fast. updating the pip still not solve the problem. i am not using proxy, vpn or anything like that.

here is the image:
[image]